# Create image map view in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to display an image with different clickable areas.
I have tried:

```
<com.ctc.android.widget.ImageMap  
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:src="@drawable/usamap"
    ctc:map="usamap"/>
```

but i didn't work with me, I think there is a missing library or something (I'm new with android studio please help)

Comment: Try this library and let me know if you have any doubts.
https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view

Comment: Thanks a lot, but can you tell me what are the steps to add it to my project ?